# How can I print using `document.getElementByID("results").innerHTML = results?

Tags: javascript, onclick, innerhtml, dice

When I click the roll button, nothing happens. Is there a way to show the results using `document.getElementByID("results").innerHTML`, or is this not recommended?

**HTML**

```
<p>How many dice?
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="numDice" />
</p>
<p>How many sides per die?
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="numSides" />
</p>
<button onclick="diceRoll()" id="roll"/>Roll!</button>
<p id="results"></p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var numDice = document.getElementByID(numDice).innerHTML;
var numSides = document.getElementByID(numSides).innerHTML;

function diceRoll() {
  var results = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
    results += (Math.random() * numSides) + 1;
  }

  document.getElementByID("results").innerHTML = results;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/jdash86/pen/oaLHC)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: Shouldn't `var numDice = document.getElementByID(numDice).innerHTML;` be `var numDice = document.getElementByID(numDice).value;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo, it's not

```
getElementByID
```

but

```
getElementById
```

The case is important, and the arguments passed are strings, so they should be quoted

```
function diceRoll() {
    var numDice = document.getElementById('numDice').value;
    var numSides = document.getElementById('numSides').value;
    var results = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
        results += (Math.round(results + (Math.random() * numSides) + 1)).toString();
    }

    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = results;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JZV9V/4/)

Comment: Wouldn't we want the value instead of innerHTML?

Comment: @j08691 - yes we would -> http://jsfiddle.net/JZV9V/

Comment: I meant to print as a string of numbers. How would I go about this? What did I do wrong here: `results += toString(Math.floor(Math.random() * numSides + 1)) + " ";`

Comment: @JohnD. - Ooh, toString comes after, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `document.getElementByID(numDice).innerHTML` *before* the DOM is ready.  The element does not exist, so this will throw an error.

You want to get the values *each* time `diceRoll()` is called, so that you get the values the user entered.  `numDice` will *not* automatically update when the value changes.

P.S. It's `getElementById`, and you want to use `.value()` for `<input>`s.

```
function diceRoll() {
  var results = "";
  var numDice = parseInt(document.getElementById('numDice').value, 10);
  var numSides = parseInt(document.getElementById('numSides').value, 10);

  for (var i = 0; i < numDice; i++) {
    results += (Math.random() * numSides) + 1;
  }

  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = results;
}
```